# Set Default Printer Option Missing in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, printing, printer, network-printer

Typically, in Windows 10, you can right-click on a printer and then the context-menu will provide you an option to set that printer as default.

Today, one of my Active Directory users reported printing issues and that she could no longer set a printer as default.

Sure enough, whether I log in as admin or as her, the "set as default printer" option is now missing:

[image]

Notice that the option to "set printer as default" is missing from the context-menu in the screen-shot above.

Any advice?

Comment: maybe it has something to do with the new default printer changes in Windows 10 ? http://www.printandshare.info/kb/articles/00003/how-to-set-the-default-printer-in-windows-10-back

Answer (score 3):

You don't need any utility to do this. As per this [Microsoft support page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4028622/windows-10-how-to-set-a-default-printer):

> To choose a default printer, select the Start button and then Settings
>   . Go to Devices > Printers & scanners > select a printer > Manage.
>   Then select Set as default. **If you have "Let Windows manage my default
>   printer" selected, you'll need to deselect it before you can choose a
>   default printer on your own**.

Answer (score 2):

On my Win10 system, you have to 'Open Queue' first, then from the 'Printer' menu, select "Set as Default Printer".

Comment: The suggestion above is good. If something has gone wrong, run dism.exe /online  /cleanup-image  /restorehealth  followed by SFC /SCANNOW and restart, test

Comment: THIS is the right answer when there's no such "Set as default printer" right after "Manage".

Answer (score 1):

Shameless plug - I wrote the following utility. It is open-sourced on [Github](https://github.com/lukebarone/DefaultPrinter) if you want to check it out yourself.

---

You can use my new app, ChangeDefaultPrinter to manually choose a default printer. It does not need to be installed, and can run in a limited user's context or an administrator context.

With Windows 10, Microsoft wants to default to managing your default printer, based on which printer you printed to last while on that network. If you don't want Windows choosing this for you, you can disable it (the app does this automatically if you choose a default printer).

To disable the automatic default, you can use the Registry Editor to edit
the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows` key. Look for a DWORD called `LegacyDefaultPrinterMode`. If it's not there, create it. Set the value to `1` to manually choose the default printer (as per previous versions of Windows), or to `0` (or delete it) to enable Windows being able to change the default.

Changes take effect immediately, without the user logging in and out. After this, you should be able to set the default printer.